# as.Date with format "mm yyyy"

Tags: r, date

In my data, a vector consists of strings like below:

```
> my_data$month
[1] "01 2000" "02 2000" "03 2000"
```

That is, the vector contains "mm yyyy" format strings.

To convert the character vector to a date vector, I tried to use the `as.Date` function:

```
tmp <- as.Date(my_data$month, format = "%m %Y")
```

But, this just returns a vector of `NA`s.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `as.Date(paste("01", my_data$month), format = "%d %m %Y")`